# Why does the library version get downgraded?

Tags: java, gradle

I try to compile logback-core in my "common" project.

```
compile "ch.qos.logback:logback-core:1.2.6"
```

After running gradle Tasks/help/dependencies this is where the logback-core lib shows up. No other lib is using a different version of logback. So why is it downgraded to .3?

```
+--- project :common
|    +--- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:1.2.6 -> 1.2.3
```